# PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrappers vs Microsoft SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server, foreign-data-wrapper

PostgreSQL provides *Foreign Data Wrappers(FDW) API* to query the external data. Is the Microsoft SQL server linked server similar to the FDWs? In postgreSQL, I can write a foreign data wrapper for my HDF5 files, CSV files, sql server table, and many other formats. Then, query them as if they are tables. Is it possible with Linked Server in MSSQL to write your own wrapper for non-relational sources?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411629/do-databases-besides-postgres-have-features-comparable-to-foreign-data-wrappers#comment78080205_23411629), they referred that MSSQL Server has Linked Server which is similar as FDW. However, I am looking for a better comparison to understand the limitations of each. In my company, Microsoft services are broadly accepted. Therefore, I need to bring a stong argument for using Foreign Data Wrappers instead of Linked Servers.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want move data between sql server and postgresql? because I dont think you can. In my case I create a C# app to do the move.

Comment: You can connect from pgsql to mssql / sybase with fdw: https://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/

Comment: It's the same concept in each individual DB.  Question is whether you want to make PostgreSQL tables accessible from within SQL Server, or SQL Server tables accessible within PostgreSQL.